# Is it possible to make a transparent container with only html while keeping text opacity?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, transparency

I would like to make my container background transparent while keeping the text/image opacity. Is it possible to do this using only html? 
Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="well text-center" >
    <div class="col-md-10"></div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/link/BDSlogo-vert-blue.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/link/skyjacker.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/link/magnaflow.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/link/jeep_poison_spyder_logo.jpeg" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why only html? You can do this with CSS...

Comment: divs are transparent by default unless your set their background to something

Comment: I'm not seeing any effort here. What's going to be the background of the container? Is it color? Is it an image? When you say _"container"_ do you mean `.container` or some other element? Please clarify and try to produce a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

I saw your question and, if I'm understanding you correctly, I think I know what you can do. One thing I noticed, before I go any further is that it looks like you are using a Bootstraps code.

It would probably be better, more efficient and possibly not break other elements of the overall code if you changed the CSS stylesheet that may be linked to this, but let's see if my solution will work for you regardless.

Basically want you want to do is:

1) write a "style" tag in your html and then put in the styling (css) properties within that (you can put it in the header of your html code to keep better track of it).

2) use the "rgba" format of providing a background color and giving it an opacity of "0" as the 4th value of the code snippet.

So, for example, the style tag in the head could be:

```
<style>.container {background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);}</style>
```

That is the only way I can think of that you can  have a transparent background, without using a stylesheet and only using CSS.

One thing I should mention is that the default color for elements (divs) is actually transparent. But I don't know if you have some special conditions in your code elsewhere that is the reason for you asking your question.

Hey, I hope that helps. Please post your results.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely keep that in mind. I will post my html and css.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I needed to change .well {  background-color: transparent;  I'll post my css. Sorry to be vague I was in a bit of a hurry.

.well {

min-height: 20px;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

I originally used a color in my chop version of the page, and have now gone back to change all containers to transparent so that my containers would display only the background of my page while keeping the opacity of the text and images used within the containers. By changing the background-color: to transparent  I seem to have solved the problem, I suppose.